# Golang reflect get nil pointer underlying type

Tags: go, reflection

I would like to know if there is a way to "cast" a nil pointer of a struct into the (empty) struct itself using reflection or anything else.

My method parameters are an empty parent struct as an interface, a field name as a string and the field value as an interface.

The point is to get the real type of the field by going through the parent struct until I find the field matching the given name. I cannot just get the type of the value, because there will be cases where it won't return the correct type (for example a time.Time will be seen as a string).

The method can take any struct as parent, which is why it takes interfaces as parameters.

My problem is that the parent struct that is given is always a empty one (it serves only as a model), with default values. So fields that are pointers to substructs are nil. So to find the field given as parameter, I have to get the underlying substruct instead of the nil pointer to continue the search inside.

I cannot find a way to achieve that, I am not sure if that's even possible.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: You don't need a non-`nil` pointer to inspect fields. Use `reflect.Type` which describes the type, not a value. Use `Type.Elem()` method to get the pointed (element) type of a type that is a pointer.

Comment: That's the thing, Type.Elem() return the Zero value if pointer is nil according to the doc. With it I get <invalid reflect.Value>, not the underlying struct.

Comment: Please note there is `Value.Elem()` and `Type.Elem()`. The former operates on values, which you can't use in case of `nil` pointer. The latter (which I suggest) operates on types, and there is no sense talking about `nil` pointer in case of types. You can call `Type.Elem()`. Probably you have and you work with `reflect.Value`, that's why I say use `reflect.Type`. Post a [mcve] if you have something that doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, I was using Value.Elem,sorry, but with Type.Elem on my *MyStruct I get a *reflect.rtype instead of a MyStruct.

Comment: But you don't want `MyStruct`, if you have the `reflect.Type` descriptor of `*MyStruct`, `Type.Elem()` will give you `reflect.Type` of `MyStruct`. You can list / step over the fields using `reflect.Type`, you don't need a `reflect.Value` for that.

Comment: But in that case what to use to get a field by its name ? FieldByName(string) is called on a reflect.Value, not a reflect.Type.

Comment: `reflect.Type` also has a `FieldByName()` method. Please consult the documentation.